# Finance API for iPhone commercial app use

Tags: ios, finance

I am planning to create a stock based app for iPhone. It's going to be a paid app. So I wanted to know what options do I have for getting the data from API.
I have heard of Yahoo finance API, but think it is not free for commercial use.

What does Apple use for their native app. Could you please provide me with other options.

Comment: Real-time and/or tick data is likely to be very expensive. Reuters or Bloomberg are probably who you need to speak to. You may also be able to license direct from exchanges.

Comment: Do you want free data or are you willing to pay?

Comment: Also - can you expand on what data you want: what stocks or exchanges, real-time or delayed, tick data or minute data, order-book data etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For historical data (historical stock quotes, historical financial statements, historical dividends, etc), you can use the APIs at http://www.mergent.com/servius

(EDIT: The API can deliver historical ratio information such as P/E ratios, but that feature is still undocumented - will be documented soon).

(EDIT: There's also http://www.zacksdata.com/zacks-data-api . By the way, as a disclosure, both APIs are managed by my company).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I did go through the link and while it seems to be close to the info I want (i.e. historical data), I am not able to find the specific info. that I want (book value, EPS, PE). Please let me know where i can find this information.

Answer (score 1):

Getting fast reliable tick data is going to be very expensive, especially if you want every tick. If you want any kind of order book depth, it's even more expensive.

You might want to investigate [LMAX](http://www.lmaxtrader.co.uk/trading-platforms/api-trading) who offer a free API. I think they are the same company that do Betfair in the UK. I'm not sure what markets they offer, whether you can use it outside the UK, and whether the prices on show are actual exchange traded prices, or from their own user generated markets, but it might be of interest...