# Paid iphone app using yahoo finance api

Tags: iphone, ios, yahoo-finance

I know that a similar question has been asked before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254405/finance-api-for-iphone-commercial-app-use) but I couldn't get an answer from there or from other posts and Yahoo website.

I'm developing an investment-tracking app (paid) and is considering to use Yahoo Finance API to obtain just a few stock quotes on launching my app, so my user don't have to enter the stock quotes manually for the stocks they entered into my apps. Not a lot of data required from the API. I am not, in a way, redistributing the data downloaded from Yahoo Finance. Is it legal to use the API in such case?

Or has anyone here used the Yahoo Finance API in paid apps and can advise me? Thanks.

Comment: After some working around with the codes, I have switched to using Yahoo YQL, which is free for commercial use, and I simply write to Yahoo! to get permission to use it. To get the stock quotes from YQL, I used the code from this [website](http://tech.element77.com/2012/02/fetching-stock-data-from-yahoo-for-ios.html).

Answer (score 1):

@Rick, I'm in a similar situation now, and I've been doing some research about Yahoo Finance and Yahoo YQL: as I understand it, YQL is built on top of Yahoo Finance, YQL is an interface to simplify access to Yahoo Finance data. Besides, YQL states that it's free for commercial use, but that you *do need* any other license or permission for any other service you might be using with YQL.

So, as I see it, you can use YQL, but you also need some kind of authorisation to retrieve data from Yahoo Finance.

Is this correct? Did Yahoo explicitly allowed you to use data from Yahoo Finance when they wrote back to you regarding your request about YQL?

Comment: On Yahoo! developer forum, they announced that Yahoo Finance is not an official API and they will acknowledge YQL only. Authorisation for using YQL is needed only if you need a higher limit of access.

Comment: Ok, I see. So the only method Yahoo provides to programatically access their financial data is through YQL (unless you do html scraping, which I think would directly violate their terms of service). Therefore, access to Yahoo Finance data is subject to the terms of service of YQL. Is this correct? By the way, do you think you could provide a link to this forum you're talking about? Thanks!

Comment: Here's the [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Re-Using-Yahoo-Finance-API-Not/1250246255000-0b82f8f0-7f48-3af2-8fe2-e73a138cbfaa)

Comment: @Rick, but in this forum you can read: _The Finance TOS is fairly specific. Redistribution of data is only allowed if you are using the badges the team has created: http://finance.yahoo.com/badges
Otherwise, you can use YQL or whatever method to obtain data for personal use._ Which means that you can use YQL, but if you want to use YQL for obtaning data from Yahoo Finance, this data cannot be used for a commercial app.

Comment: But I'm sure there must be some way... there's tons of commercial apps that use Yahoo Finance somehow ... Look at [Stock Market Eye](http://www.stockmarketeye.com/), for example.

Comment: @Rick, who did you write to in order to get permission to use YQL?